# Collecting the keys from array of objects and reducing it into a single array and removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extract the keys of each object in the array, then i will collect all the keys , after that i concatenate the small chunk key arrays. Then i use set to eliminate duplicates and get all the keys.

I am able to get the result. Is there any better approach for this

Any help appreciated

```js
let data = [
  {
    "test1": "123",
    "test2": "12345",
    "test3": "123456"
  },
  {
    "test1": "123",
    "test2": "12345",
    "test3": "123456"
  },
  {
    "test1": "123",
    "test2": "12345",
    "test3": "123456"
  },
  {
    "test1": "123",
    "test2": "12345",
    "test3": "123456"
  },
  {
    "test1": "123",
    "test2": "12345",
    "test3": "123456"
  },
]

let keysCollection = []

data.forEach(d => {
  let keys = Object.keys(d);
  keysCollection.push(keys)
})


let mergingKeysCollection = keysCollection.reduce((a,b) => [...a, ...b], [])

let uniqueKeys = new Set(mergingKeysCollection)

console.log('uniqueKeys', uniqueKeys)
```

Comment: What you have done actually works, it's just that Sets don't stringify..  So to make yours work just do -> `let uniqueKeys = Array.from(new Set(mergingKeysCollection))` or even `let uniqueKeys = [...new Set(mergingKeysCollection))]`

Comment: @Keith or `console.log('uniqueKeys', Array.from(uniqueKeys))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take directly a set without using another array of keys.

```js
let data = [{ test1: "123", test2: "12345", test3: "123456" }, { test1: "123", test2: "12345", test3: "123456" }, { test1: "123", test2: "12345", test3: "123456" }, { test1: "123", test2: "12345", test3: "123456" }, { test1: "123", test2: "12345", test3: "123456" }],
    uniqueKeys = Array.from(
        data.reduce((r, o) => Object.keys(o).reduce((s, k) => s.add(k), r), new Set)
    );

console.log(uniqueKeys)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{"test1":"123","test2":"12345","test3":"123456"},{"test1":"123","test2":"12345","test3":"123456"},{"test1":"123","test2":"12345","test3":"123456"},{"test1":"123","test2":"12345","test3":"123456"},{"test1":"123","test2":"12345","test3":"123456"},];

const res = data.reduce((unique, item) => (Object.keys(item).forEach(key => unique.add(key)), unique), new Set);

console.log([...res]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```